# How to set up heroku? Content updates disappear

Tags: heroku

I am making changes to the content of the site on heroku. After about 1.5 hours, everything rolls back. Disconnecting from GIT didn't help. Is there any other setting?

Comment: You are almost certainly modifying the local filesystem, e.g. by using a file-based database like SQLite or saving uploaded content like images. Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) is quite well documented and [frequently asked about here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheroku%5D+changes+lost).

Comment: I recommend checking out Render (full disclosure: I work there). It's similar to Heroku, but has Disks (https://render.com/docs/disks) so you can persist data that's in SQLite.